# Bluebird promise-based request handler in Express returning error

Tags: node.js, express, redis, promise, bluebird

I'm using Express (4.x), Redis (2.8) and Bluebird (2.x) - Needed to string together multiple Redis calls to return a response:

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var redis   = require('redis');
var redis = redis.createClient(6379,process.env["REDIS_ENDPOINT"],{});
promise.promisifyAll(redis);

// GET

exports.inOffers = function (req, res) {
    return redis.smembersAsync('advertisers')
    .map(function(advId){
        console.log('advId',advId);
        return redis.smembersAsync('advertiser:'+advId+':inoffers')
            .map(function(inOfferId){
                console.log('offerId: ',inOfferId);
                return redis.hgetallAsync('advertiser:'+advId+':inoffer:'+inOfferId);
            })
    })
    .done(function(inOffers){
        console.log('InOffers: ',inOffers);
        res.json({inOffers: inOffers})
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log((new Date).toUTCString()+" [ERROR] ", err);
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
    });
};
```

According to the logs, the data is gathered correctly from Redis, but I get the following error, instead of a response:

> /var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:95
>                   throw res.e;
>                            ^ Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Any ideas? I'm new to bluebird, probably messed something up...

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `.done` with `.then`

Answer (score -1):

To clarify, and as Benjamin pointed out below, your issue is that you are trying to set the headers on the response object after it has already been sent to the client.  I'm not sure if there is other middleware that is returning a response, or if it something with the .done/.catch you have there. I would try the code below for the end of your promise chain, although I'm not sure it will help.  Another tip - per bluebird docs, you don't need to use 'done', although you can if you want to ([bluebird .done docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#donefunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----void)).  If you do use .done, it should be the last thing in your promise chain (although you can have both fulfilled and rejected handlers on it, just like .then).

```
.done(function(inOffers){
    console.log('InOffers: ',inOffers);
    res.json({inOffers: inOffers})
}, function(err){
    console.log((new Date).toUTCString()+" [ERROR] ", err);
    res.writeHead(500);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Definitely not the issue. OP's issue isn't with promises - it's what its saying - he's sent the headers elsewhere in the app and now trying to send them again (setting the content type to JSON for instance). If you remove the res/req parts of that code it's work. `.done` is an artifact from the olden days of promise libraries who didn't detect unhandled rejections.

Comment: I realize the issue is that the response is trying to get sent twice, I thought it might be related to the catch coming after the done, so if there is an error in res.json the catch might get triggered.  I changed it so only one of the response methods could be called.  I was also taking the time to point out that he didn't have to use .done, and that .catch after .done doesn't really make sense.  It doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: No, but that's likely his real code anyway since `.done` returns `undefined`.